# How fast invalidate refreshers the canvas?

Tags: android

if i call invlidate() at the end of onDraw() function in a View, at what rate does the system refreshers?.

In emulator it takes around 1 second to call the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you using the canvas for?  If you're doing a game or something that needs to be refreshed constantly you should really use a SurfaceView.  That will take care of calling the draw method at regular intervals without you having to call invalidate.  That said the refresh rate of a SurfaceView really depends on what you're drawing.  If all you're doing is clearing it then it can do many hundreds of frames per second.

Comment: is it possible use just a view and somehow invalidate correctly? I draw rect, when I change its value: visible to false I invalidate it. But sometimes that shape is not redrawed.. Any help?

Comment: You can call `invalidate()` and pass in a rect that tells it what part of the screen to redraw.

Comment: When you use a SurfaceView and your drawing methods are very short, your refresh rate can only be as high as the display hardware refresh rate. Typically this means 60 frames a second not many hundreds.